# How to know that property was changed from View

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

My silverlight project uses MVVM.For examlpe, I have textbox, that binded to ViewModel property. Textbox content can change from View or ViewModel. I need know when content changed from View. How can I implement this accordingly MVVM?

Comment: This question has already been asked, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671872/wpf-listbox-commands/6672153#6672153

Answer (score 0):

If your viewmodel has INotifyPropertyChanged/INotifyPropertyChanging implemented then you can hook into it. That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you use [bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), you get the information in your setter.
Here is a little example:
XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

C# of your ViewModel:

```
private string myProperty = "Test";

        public String MyProperty
        {
            get { return myProperty; }
            set
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Property set");
                myProperty = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
            }
        }
```

Each time, you change the text and the TextBox looses the focus, the setter get called.
If you want to get the setter called each time you hit a key, have a look [here](http://thegrayzone.co.uk/blog/2010/10/update-silverlight-textbox-binding-source-on-change/). This is a little bit of a quick and dirty solution for triggering the binding ;) A better way would be to write an Behaviour for this.

Hope this helps!

BR,

TJ